# Trying to find an element that is a submenu in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How would I use the web driver to find an element that is a sort of submenu like this code below. I have tried finding it by its class name like this

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\chromedriver_win32");
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("{img: '16-member-remove.png")).Click();
```

And that hasn't worked.
if you need any more info just ask, thanks.

This is the buttons html code

```
<a
    href="javascript:setMenuId('EmployViewMenu', '0', 'b532931583354d4890fbd6884835760e', 'EmployViewMenu_MenuIdHiddenField', '1', 'EmployViewMenu_PostbackButton');"
    class="{img: '16-member-remove.png'}"
    tabindex="0"
    img="16-member-remove.png">
    New Client
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a horrible class name to have and base your locator on. Just get the element by *link text*:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("New Client"));
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("New Client"));
```